# How to test code that loops forever

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have an app ([epazote](https://github.com/epazote/epazote/blob/master/block.go)) that once starts runs forever but I want to test some values before it blocks/waits until <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> is pressed or is killed.

Here is an small example: http://play.golang.org/p/t0spQRJB36

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
)

type IAddString interface {
    AddString(string)
}

type addString struct{}

func (self *addString) AddString(s string) {
    fmt.Println(s)
}

func block(a IAddString, s string) {

    // test this
    a.AddString(s)


    // ignore this while testing
    block := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(block, os.Interrupt, os.Kill)

    for {
        signalType := <-block
        switch signalType {

        default:
            signal.Stop(block)
            fmt.Printf("%q signal received.", signalType)
            os.Exit(0)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    a := &addString{}
    block(a, "foo")
}
```

I would like to know if is posible to ignore some parts of the code while testing, or how to test this cases, I have implemented an interface, in this case for testing `AddString`  that helped me to test some parts but have no idea of how to avoid the "block" and test.

Any ideas?

**Update**: Putting the code inside the loop `Addstring` in another function works but only for testing that function, but If I want to do a full code coverage, I still need to check/test the blocking part, for example how to test that is properly behaving when receiving <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or a `kill -HUP`, I was thinking on maybe creating a fake `signal.Notify` but don't know how to overwrite imported packages in case that could work.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Put the code that is inside the loop in a separate function, and unit test that function without the loop.

Comment: I agree with @GolezTrol.  Golez, you should put that in the answer section so I can upvote it ;-)

Comment: A code that loops forever? I would like to know a good scenario when it is good to have an infinite loop. That is really bad for performance. Isn't it?

Comment: Looping forever has nothing really to do with performance.  For example, typically when you listen for tcp connections you infinite loop on a call to "Accept", which blocks until someone connects to your socket.  It doesn't busy spin and eat cpu

Comment: Reading your update.. There is stuff that can't be unit tested. You have to live with that. All kinds of IO, the main function, and also this endless loop are just untestable, or at least untestable using a unit test, unless you have some exit condition that can be triggered from a test. But still, is it worth the effort? Code coverage is useful to measure to a certain degree, but 100% coverage doesn't mean you got all your scenarios tested either. Focus on the quality of the tests that test your core functionality first.

Comment: Yeah, you need to question why you are testing. I would argue that `block` is not a unit as far as unit testing goes. One guideline I use is that unit tests run in the same process as the code being tested. What's the requirement you're trying to satisfy?

Comment: Also, your specific code is kinda pointless. Go's default handlers do what you're doing

Comment: @nfirvine Hi can you please explain more about the handlers or give more details?

Comment: I might be able to find a reference in the runtime source. What I'm saying is, if you simplified to just "for {}", you'd have the same program functionally (minus the print).

Comment: Actually, generally, you don't unit test package main. Put your units (AddString) in their own package, and test that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Introduce test delegates into your code.

Extract your loop into a function that takes 2 functions as arguments: onBeginEvent and onEndEvent.  The functions signatures shall take:

- state that you want to inspect inside the test case
- optional: counter of loop number (so you can identify each loop).  It is optional because actual delegate implementation can count number of times it was invoked by itself.

In the beginning of your loop you call OnBegingEvent(counter, currentState); than your code does its normal work and in the end you call OnEndEvent(counter, currentState);  Presumably your code has changed currentState.

In production you could use an empty implementation of the function delegates or implement nil check in your loop.

You can use this model to put as many checks of your processing algorithms as you want.  Let's say you have 5 checks.  Now you look back at it and realize that's becoming too hard.  You create an Interface that defines your callback  functions. These callback functions are a powerful method of changing your service behavior.  You step back one more time and realize that interface is actually your "service's policy" ;)

Once you take that route you will want to stop your infinite loop somehow.  If you want a tight control within a test case you could take a 3rd function delegate that returns true if it is time to quit from the loop. Shared variable is an option to control quit condition.

This is certainly a higher level of testing than unit testing and it is necessary in complex services.

Comment: There's a lot here. I was there was code.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it's possible. Put the code that is inside the loop in a separate function, and unit test that function without the loop.